# Load data on startup and save on shutdown

Tags: java, database, spring, caching

Please suggest on what is the best way to do this with Spring / Java:

- Load data from DB to a data structure (HashMap) on startup
- Update this memory during the application lifecycle
- Update the DB with data from memory every x number of minutes
- Update the DB with data from memory upon shutdown of server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the initialization part you can use either init method marker or [`@PostConstruct`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-postconstruct-and-predestroy-annotations)  annotation on initialization method.

For the shutdown you can use [`@PreDestroy`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-postconstruct-and-predestroy-annotations) annotation on shutdown method.

For regular update you can use [`@Scheduled`](https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/)  annotation.

For the variable containing the data it would be worth using ConcurrentHashMap so it doesn't become bottleneck.

```
 @PostConstruct
 public void init() {
       // load the data
 }
 ...
 @PreDestroy
 @Scheduled(fixedRate = 60L * 1000L)
 public void writeCached() {
     // update data to database
 }
```